# SVN Post-Commit Hook error 255

Tags: svn, bash, post-commit, post-commit-hook

I am trying to create a very simple post-commit hook for a repository I have set up on my server. The script is as follows:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

cd /var/www/directory && svn update --username user --password pass
```

When I run a commit from my SVN client, I get the following error:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.
```

However, when I run my post-commit hook from cli with sudo bash post-commit, it executes perfectly. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

255 means a file wasn't found, try using the absolute path to all files:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

cd /var/www/directory && /usr/bin/svn update --username user --password pass
```

The PATH env variable of the environment in which the post commit hook is running probably isn't set to include wherever the SVN executable lives.

Comment: Hmmm... no luck. I have made this change, and verified that svn is located at /usr/bin, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Make sure to chmod +x the hook script. I was getting "post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output." I had copied post-commit.tmpl to post-commit but did not change it to be executable.

Comment: Another thing to mindful of is that the server id ("apache" in my case) specifically needs execute permission to the file (either by ownership or group/world access).  Personally ran into a project where my pre-commit script was group executable, but overlooked that apache was not in that project group.  Since apache already owned pre-commit.tmpl, just moved that to pre-commit, as I did not want to add world execute nor hassle with managing apache's groups.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I have figured out the issue. It was a combination of a path issue (as suggested by chown, whose answer I will choose) and a permissions issue. I have written a blog post about the issue (as well as generally getting set up with SVN) which can be found at [http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com](http://brennydoogles.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/using-subversion-to-automatically-publish-your-website/)

Answer (score 1):

- Don't forget add `#!/bin/sh` in your post-commit hook.Use `#!/bin/env python` if you are using python
- Make sure the permission `chmod a+x post-commit`
- Make sure commands in your hook is installed and reachable.

---

I meet this problem when running SVN in a docker(base on ubuntu) and use a post-commit hook for my Redmine sync:

```
curl "http://my.redmine.ip/sys/fetch_changesets?id=myproject&key=ETji9KUfs3XxLyyr6cRN"
```

I got error `Warning: post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output`.

Then I bash into my docker, run this hook manually and find out that 'curl' is not installed.

I install curl and run hook successfully, but still the same warning when commit.

After add `#!/bin/sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl "http://my.redmine.ip/sys/fetch_changesets?id=myproject&key=ETji9KUfs3XxLyyr6cRN"
```

Everything is fine.

Comment: Yup, I forgot chmod+x

Answer (score 1):

Also if the svn server is running under apache, and the operating system is running SElinux, remember to give apache permission to run the script, as in:

% chcon -t httpd_exec_t /home/svn/repos/hooks/post-commit